# Parameters - Requiring Some But Not Others - Correct Use of Parameter Sets

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, parameter-sets

So I'm experimenting with PowerShell and having a little trouble understanding parameters. From what I've read if I specify a parameter to be at the same position as another but place it in a separate ParameterSet PowerShell will only require one of these parameters to be present.

In this example that works as expected -

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='MultiUser')]

Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
[string]$Token,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2, ParameterSetName="MultiUser")]
[string]$UsernamesFile,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2, ParameterSetName="SingleUser")]
[string]$SingleUsername,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[switch]$SpecialCase
)
```

But if I wanted to expand on this so that as above you have to specify a token and then you must specify either a single username ***or*** a usernames files but now I would like to specify a group the user was going to be in.

Now let's assume the user has to go into one of two groups and I don't want to worry about dealing with different ways a user may input a group name so I use two switches. I only want the user to be in a single group rather than both so the switches should be at the same position but in different parameter sets (based on what I've read and that the above example works).

So my second example looks like this -

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='MultiUser')]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
[string]$Token,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2, ParameterSetName="MultiUser")]
[string]$UsernamesFile,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2, ParameterSetName="SingleUser")]
[string]$SingleUsername,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=3, ParameterSetName="GroupA")]
[switch]$GroupA,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=3, ParameterSetName="GroupB")]
[switch]$GroupB,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[switch]$SpecialCase
)
```

This doesn't work as expected however, this gives me an error -

[image: New Parameters Can't Be Found]

Could someone explain why this doesn't work and correct my understanding of PowerShell parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: As Mathias' answer is a good solution but misses some explanation: At the point you specify the `$usernamesFile` you choosed ParameterSet _'MultiUser'_. As `$GroupA` isn't in _'MultiUser '_, it's an invalid Parameter and vice versa. As you gave both parameters, PowerShell cannot decide which ParameterSet to use.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the explanation :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>See bottom for an explanation of the problem with the OP's approach.</sup>

To **get exactly what you're asking for**, you'd have to use the following:

```
# - Make sure that parameters are NON-positional unless explicitly marked otherwise.
# - Specify the default parameter set.
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$False, DefaultParameterSetName='MultiUserA')]
Param(

  # Belongs to all parameter sets.
  [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=1)]
  [string]$Token,

  # Mandatory and positional both when combined with -GroupA or -GroupB.
  [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=2, ParameterSetName='MultiUserA')]
  [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=2, ParameterSetName='MultiUserB')]
  [string] $UsernamesFile,

  # Mandatory - but not positional - both when combined with -GroupA or -GroupB.
  [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='SingleUserA')]
  [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='SingleUserB')]
  [string] $SingleUsername,

  # Mandatory, whether combined with -UsernamesFile or -SingleUsername
  [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='SingleUserA')]
  [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='MultiUserA')]
  [switch] $GroupA,

  # Mandatory, whether combined with -UsernamesFile or -SingleUsername
  [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='SingleUserB')]
  [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='MultiUserB')]
  [switch] $GroupB,

  # Belongs to all parameter sets. Non-mandatory by default.
  [switch] $SpecialCase

)
```

As you can see,

- You need to define *4* parameter sets that amount to all users-file-vs.-single-user and groupA-vs.-group-B *combinations*.
- You need to assign each parameter to *multiple* parameter sets, choosing the appropriate subset.

  - Note that each `[Parameter(...)]` attribute can only specify *1* parameter set, and whatever other attributes you specify there - `Mandatory`, `Position`, ... - apply to the parameter *only in the context of the given parameter set*.

When you invoke your script with `-?` (or pass it to `Get-Help`) you'll see the resulting syntax diagram:

```
script.ps1 [-Token] <string> [-UsernamesFile] <string> -GroupA [-SpecialCase] [<CommonParameters>]
script.ps1 [-Token] <string> [-UsernamesFile] <string> -GroupB [-SpecialCase] [<CommonParameters>]
script.ps1 [-Token] <string> -SingleUsername <string> -GroupB [-SpecialCase] [<CommonParameters>]
script.ps1 [-Token] <string> -SingleUsername <string> -GroupA [-SpecialCase] [<CommonParameters>]
```

However, this **approach is ill-advised** for the following reasons:

- You shouldn't have *mandatory* `[switch]` parameters, as they're by definition *optional*.
- When you invoke the script without parameters for *interactive* argument entry, PowerShell won't let you specify a switch value (no values I've tried work: not `true`, `false`, `1`, `0`, ... - try with `./script someToken someFile`)
- `./script.ps1 someToken -SingleUsername someUser` gives a generic error message (`Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`) rather than specifically pointing out that either `-GroupA` or `-GroupB` is missing, because PowerShell cannot know whether you meant parameter set `SingleUserA` or `SingleUserB`.

  - By contrast, `./script someToken someFile` - with implied `-UsernamesFile` - is unambiguous, because `MultiUserA` is the *default* parameter set, but due to the `-GroupA` switch being *mandatory*, you still get a prompt for its value).
- Last, but not least, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, using distinct, mutually exclusive switches (`-GroupA` vs. `-GroupB`) doesn't scale well, as adding more `-Group*` switches quickly makes the number of combinations that must each be reflected in their own parameter set unmanageable - see below for how to avoid that.

---

As pointed out in [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018496/45375), the **better approach** is to use a ***single parameter*** for the target group that **accepts only a value from a given set of values**, which the `[ValidationAttribute]` can ensure:

```
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$False, DefaultParameterSetName='MultiUser')]
Param(

  [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=1)]
  [string] $Token,

  [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=2, ParameterSetName='MultiUser')]
  [string] $UsernamesFile,

  [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='SingleUser')]
  [string] $SingleUsername,

  # Single -Group parameter that only accepts values 'GroupA' and 'GroupB'
  # Input validation is case-INsensitive, as usual.
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [ValidateSet('GroupA', 'GroupB')]
  [string] $Group,

  [switch] $SpecialCase

)
```

This gives us the following syntax diagrams (note that the set of valid values for `-Group` is *not* reflected):

```
script.ps1 [-Token] <string> [-UsernamesFile] <string> -Group <string> [-SpecialCase] [<CommonParameters>]
script.ps1 [-Token] <string> -SingleUsername <string> -Group <string> [-SpecialCase] [<CommonParameters>]
```

- This reduces the number of required parameter sets to *2*.
- It supports interactive entry of the group name (although, somewhat unfortunately, supplying an invalid name *aborts* the invocation).
- If you omit `-Group`, both the `./script.ps someToken someFile` and the `./script.ps someToken -SingleUserName someUser` now behave the same: they prompt for the `-Group` value.
- While having to type `-Group` *and* a value is perhaps slightly more cumbersome on invocation than having distinct switches `-GroupA` and `-GroupB`,

  - it is the more extensible approach, should the number of groups grow over time,
  - tab completion does work to expand / cycle through the valid values.

---

As for **problems with your original approach**:

- As [Clijsters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4068240/clijsters) points out, your attempt to invoke `./script.ps1 -Token a -UsernamesFile someFile -GroupA` failed, because:

  - PowerShell needs to *unambiguously* resolve the given combination of parameters to a parameter set.
  - `-GroupA` *only* belongs to parameter set `GroupA`, whereas `-UsersnameFile` *only* belongs to parameter set `MultiUser`, so these parameters are in effect *mutually exclusive*, and PowerShell cannot determine what parameter set to use.
- All non-switch parameters are *positional* *by default* - unless you explicitly deactivate that with `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$False,...)]` - then only individual `[Parameter(...)]` attributes explicitly marked with a `Position` attribute become positional.
- Also, there is no point in making a `[switch]` parameter *positional*, as they're by definition non-positional: you always have to specify their *name* (unambiguously), and that allows them to be placed anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would merge the two switches and take input based on which group you want them in.

You can use the `ValidateSet` validation attribute to ensure that the user specifies one of two specific groups

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$Token,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2, ParameterSetName="MultiUser")]
    [string]$UsernamesFile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2, ParameterSetName="SingleUser")]
    [string]$SingleUsername,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=3)]
    [ValidateSet('A','B')]
    [string]$Group,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [switch]$SpecialCase
)
```